# How to sniff http requests

Tags: asp.net, http, packet-sniffers

I want to sniff a local HTTP request to an ASP.NET web application.

Is telnet an option?

How do you capture packets to a web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this in another post, it works

http://socketsniff.nirsoft-freeware.qarchive.org/_download2.html

Answer (score 18):

Depending on your exact requirements, [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/) may be sufficient.

Comment: +1 Fiddler is actually one of the most robust tools I've found for the Windows platform. It also comes with a FireFox plugin so that you can easily utilize it cross-browser (other browsers require some hand configuration, but still work).

Comment: It looks real cool, but it doesn't seem to work in games such as Starcraft 2, that search for open game lobbies to gather players to play. I wanted to replicate the requests, and request for it with my own tool :\

Answer (score 3):

**http://www.wireshark.org/** is a very advanced and free sniffer/protocol analyzer. I use it on our servers to monitor things from sip protocol info to raw http data. Its all you need and you can add filter rules to just get the data from certain IP etc. ie:

ip.addr == 192.168.1.1

Raw packets and headers all included.

Answer (score 1):

For ease of setup, I personally would use either the Tamper Data (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966) or Live HTTP Headers (https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/3829) plugin for the FireFox browser - or for a lower level solution WireShark (http://www.wireshark.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried browser plugins that allow you to do this? Firebug, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are browser add-ins that can make sniffing of the HTTP requests easy:

For Internet Explorer, there is the [Fiddler Web Debugger](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

For Firefox, there is the [Live HTTP Headers add-in](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829).

Comment: Fiddler actually works with any browser, though it does need .NET (so probably isn't terribly convenient to run on anything but Windows).

Comment: @SamB -- good point. It'd been so long since I used Fiddler I'd forgotten that you can set it's localhost:port as the proxy for other browsers.