# Get the parameters in Request

Tags: parameters, httpwebrequest

How do I get the parameters that are available in the request Header? When I login to a site, I need to see the values that are available in the request header.Is it possible to get that information using any Addons? Can someone please help me to find this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630780/how-to-sniff-http-requests

Answer (score 0):

[FireFox TamperData](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966) is the closest thing I can think of off the top of my head,  it shows you what is in the current request/response headers and allows you to manipulate them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've a question, our application sets the user name in header. So in the java code I can get that using request.getHeader("paramName"). Is it possible to see that "paramName" using any plugins? Is that part of HTTP Header?