# Program for windows which can display HTTP request made by PHP?

Tags: php

Like firebug shows ajax request made by javascript is there any similar tool for windows which can show http request made through CURL from PHP while working locally on WAMP ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.wireshark.org/ or http://www.effetech.com/sniffer/

Also see other answers

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437038/http-and-https-sniffer-for-windows
- [How to sniff http requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630780/how-to-sniff-http-requests)

Google "HTTP Analyzer", "Protocol Analyzer", "HTTP Sniffer" etc for alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want the HTTP headers?

If you have curl on windows,

```
curl http://example.com -D -
```

gives you the HTTP headers also. ( the '-' after the '-D' tell it to spit it to stdout (works on *nix, not sure about windows) , you can replace the '-' with  a filename
eg:

```
curl http://example.com -D headers.txt
```

)

Or you can look it up on the other side of the universe with Apache access logs (as you are working locally). I dont have Windows here, but you might have to configure it to log,

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html#accesslog

Comment: @open-source-lover , did you mean [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) this curl ?

Answer (score 2):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) should be able to catch curl too, and it has a quite complete interface.